# Ember loading values on controller load

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am attempting load an array of genres, for use as select values. Multiple selects can be created using an addSelect action.  Here's how I load the data.

```
genreStrings: function() {
    var array = [];
    this.store.findAll("genre").then(function(genres){
        genres.forEach(function(genre){
            array.push(genre.get('combinedName'));
        });
    });
    return array;
}.property(),
```

And then it's used in the template like so.

```
{{view "select" content=genreStrings value=genre.name prompt="Select a Genre" }}
```

The problem I face is that the first select that loads as the page loads has no values, whilst each subsequent one, added by using the addSelect action has the values as expected.

I have tried `.on('init')` but this still isn't working.

How can I get these values to be set for the first select?

Answer (score 0):

For the first time, the array is just empty, as you used the asynchronous way to load the data. The solution could be rather to create a method that updates the `genres` field:

```
  genres: null,

  genreStrings: Ember.computed.map('genres', function(genre) {
    return genre.get('combinedName');
  }).property('genres'),

  genreStrings: function() {
    this.set('genres', []);
    this.store.findAll("genre").then(function(genres) {
      this.set('genres', genres);
    }.bind(this));
  }.on('init')
```

Additionally, I've added `Ember.computed.map` that transforms `genres` to the desired format. You can still use ES5 style:

```
  genreStrings: function() {
    return this.get('genres').map(function(genre) {
      return genre.get('combinedName');
    });
  }).property('genres'),
```

---

EDIT:

if you want to do it in more Ember way, you can move it to the route's model hook:

```
model: function() {
  return this.store.findAll("genre");
}
```

Then, if you return the promise, the whole route will wait for your data to be fetched and in your controller, you'll have it in the `model` property.

Comment: This works, but it might be more Ember-y to load the data in the route instead.